# What is the "Use compiler from module target JDK when possible" option?

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ if you go to Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler, there's an option called "Use compiler from module target JDK when possible".

[image]

I wonder what is meant by "when possible". When would it not be possible? And in the case when it's not possible, what will be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [IntelliJ IDEA documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2021.1/java-compiler.html#javac_eclipse):

[image: when possible]

When it's not possible to use the module JDK, build process JDK will be used which is the same JDK as used to run IntelliJ IDEA (currently JetBrains Runtime bundled with the IDE is based on JDK 11).

Comment: I see the same problem: When I uncheck this option and build project, idea will use Idea-setup-root\jbr\bin\java.exe to build which current version is 17.0.6.

But I want idea build this project use Project JDK whick version is 1.8, although I set the Project JDK and Module JDK used Project JDK, it still doesn't work!

This is wired...